# Javascript (Vue) call function from other js file return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to call my notification function from other JS file but it always return `undefined`.

notification.js

```
function notification(message, level = 'success') {
    Lobibox.notify(level, {
        delayIndicator: false,
        msg: message

    });
}
```

addToCart.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
    <button class="button dark small" @click="addToCart(menu, price)">
        <i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg m-right-5"></i>
        Pilih Menu
    </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['menu', 'price'],

        methods:{
            addToCart(menu, price){
                const currentPoint = $('#current_point').val();

                if(price > currentPoint){
                    return notification('Point is not enough', 'error')
                }


            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('addtocart', require('./components/AddToCart.vue'));
new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

html:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/notification.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Every time `price > currentPoint` get called it always return me `Uncaught ReferenceError: notification is not defined`.

I compile it using LaravelMix.

Any solution?

Comment: Your notification method does not have any return statement. So it returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notification.js

```
function notification(message, level = 'success') {
    Lobibox.notify(level, {
        delayIndicator: false,
        msg: message

    });
}

window.notification = notification;
```

Solve it. I need to add `window.notification = notification` so I can call it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to do following in your HTML:

```
<script src="js/notification.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I use Laravel. My code will render exactly the same like yours

Answer (score 0):

it's better to avoid putting things in window.

It looks like you're using the Vue with webpack. If you're not, then this won't work. If you are, you're better off using ES6 modules to make sure you have access to things where you need them.

Within your notification.js file:

```
export default user
```

Which you can then call on

```
import notification from 'notification'
```